# Django Channels App Websocket Connection Failing

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, django-channels, daphne, asgi

I believe I have a similar issue to the one found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66758430/django-chat-app-websocket-connection-to-wss-failed)
and [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229577/websocket-error-using-django-channels-with-ec2)

The gist is that I'm running a Django app with channels on an Amazon-ec2 instance and the websockets are failing to connect.

Most of my code regarding the websockets comes from the django-channels tutorial [here.](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/index.html)

Traffic is being directed though secured dns name behind an application load balancer.

I'm running this entirely on Daphne (handling both https and websocket traffic) with pretty minimal configurations:

```
daphne -b <server_url> -p <port> test_app.asgi:application
```

I'm also authenticating with openID-connect using the **mozilla-django-oidc** module. However for the websocket test I'm not expecting authentication. I feel it's worth pointing out if the issue is related to websocket authentication in any way.

In development I'm running a local redis cluster as my channel layer. My dev app (all http:// and ws://) has no issues connecting to websockets. The chat app works as expected. I can connect to my websockets and is confirmed with a

```
127.0.0.1:60779 - - [07/Apr/2021:12:06:05] "WSCONNECTING /ws/chat/lobby/"
```

Here is the code in asgi.py

```
import chat.routing

asgi_app = get_asgi_application()
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
   {
       "http": asgi_app,
       "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
           URLRouter(chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)
       ),
   }
)
```

and the code in chat/routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/(?P<room_name>\w+)/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

In production I'm using an elasticache redis cluster as my channel layer. I can test this in the django shell and it connects/sends/receives.

However in the production chat I am unable to reach the room or see the above **WSCONNECTING** message. It never upgrades the connection to a websocket.
The next log after that is

```
2021-04-07 16:15:15,279 WARNING  Not Found: /ws/chat/lobby/
```

Like its trying to resolve that route as http and not as a websocket.

After doing some additional reading I tried to use the host/port that is running on Daphne like

```
wss://<my host ip>:<port>/ws/chat/lobby
```

Which did not cause an immediate failure but ultimately never connected.

```
(index):46 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
```

Here's the error in chrome
[image]

I feel like it's something to do with that public-facing host name that is being used as the host name in the websocket url. All inbound traffic is allowed. I'm not sure how this relates to the issue at hand.

I'm still trying to learn my way around all this. Any advice would certainly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you providing authenticaion in request (as you have used AuthMiddlewareStack). Also is your redis-server configured properly? [check-this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-18-04). Also make sure this runs properly on localhost before deploying this ensure no error in **consumer.py** code.

As you said you are following official doc of django-channels do look at the production use of django channels [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html) this one is must.

Answer (score 0):

I was just running thru that same tutorial, and I got the same error. I decided to look at the methods imported here:

> from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

and I couldn't find them. So I uninstalled django-channels and installed channels

> python3 -m pip uninstall django-channels && python3 -m pip install channels

and stuff worked.